# JaveEE core lib unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm having troubles using the core lib. 
Here's the context: Spring tool Suite (custom eclipse based on Luna 4.4.2) with Maven, on a TomEE server.

On a .jsp page, I use an import 
There's no problem with that.

On the imported page, I have others tag like
">link
who does not work.
My browser is looking for the following url:
http://localhost:8080/pro/

A simple link  works perfectly fine, so the issue is located on the tag c:

The first jsp has the @taglib declaration, the import pages do not. When both got the @taglib, there's no probleme. That's the point.
As the second .jsp is imported in the first one, who already got the taglib, there should be no need to duplicate this code.

It took me some time to figure out where the problem was located, I just copied these two pages from another project running on standard Eclipse (Luna, 4.4.1) using tomcat7 and everything was fine with only one @taglib declaration.

Could you tell me more about this odd behaviour ?

update:

home file :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

(...)

<c:import url="inc/import.jsp"/>
```

It's ok with the following file:
import.jsp file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

(...)

<a href="<c:url value='link' />">link</a>
```

This does not work:
import.jsp file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

(...)

<a href="<c:url value='link' />">link</a>
```

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Tell us exactly what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. If any error message or stack trace, post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is perfectly normal and expected. `<c:import>` is not a static include. When invoked with an absolute URL, it sends an HTTP request to the URL, get the result and includes it in the calling page. When invoked with a relative URL, it does a dynamic include using the RequestDispatcher.

What you expect to happen would happen if you used a static include, which is basically as if the code of the included JSP was copied and pasted inside the first one:

```
<%@include file="inc/import.jsp" %>
```